# groovy ActionListener doesn't work under one condition

Tags: java, swing, groovy

I am writing simple calc in groovy with swing. I declare buttons in a loop and add AcionListeners to them at the same time. The think is that listeners work for each button except "=" button. I don't know what seems to be the problem here. Can You help me with that?

```
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.*
import java.awt.event.*

frame = new JFrame(size: [600, 300], layout: new FlowLayout())
msgLabel = new JLabel("")
frame.contentPane.add msgLabel
def characters = "0123456789,/*-+=C"

0.upto(characters.length()-1) {
    def sign = characters.getAt(it)
    button = new JButton(sign)
    frame.contentPane.add button

    println this.getClass().getName()

    if(sign == "=") {
        button.addActionListener({ equals() } as ActionListener)
    } else if(sign == "C") {
        button.addActionListener({ clear() } as ActionListener)
    } else {
        button.addActionListener({ putText(sign) } as ActionListener)
    }
}


frame.show()

public void equals() {
    println "equals"
}

public void clear() {
    println "clear"
}

public void putText(sign) {
    println sign
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, in groovy, `==` is actually `equals` under the hoods.

Comment: @jalopaba: thanks for the information! I'll delete my erroneous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "equals" method to "result" and you are done:

```
button.addActionListener({ result() } as ActionListener)

[...]

public void result() {
    println "equals"
}
```

or use "this" to avoid the hidding/scope problem you are likely suffering:

```
button.addActionListener({ this.equals() } as ActionListener)

[...]

public void equals() {
    println "equals"
}
```

Right now I'm not sure which object `equals()` method is hiding yours, but I just tested the above solutions in the groovy console (2.3.6) and they are working.

**EDIT**: You can "avoid" the closure coercion to [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) doing `button.actionPerformed = closure`, i.e.:

```
if(sign == '=') {
    button.actionPerformed = { println '=' }
} else if(sign == 'C') {
    button.actionPerformed = { println 'clear' }
} else {
    button.actionPerformed = { println sign }
}
```